Running all scripts in an R project, in different folders which contain multiple folders
I am trying to run all R scripts in a project. The project and the run_scripts.R script are in a parent folder, and all scripts are in child folders which contain many folders and the script_n.R.
How could I fix the code so that I could include all source(...) commands and run all script_n.R in different folders?
I'm using R packages misty and MplusAutomation so I need to have all R scripts in different folders. Each script writes data into a data folder inside the child folder and so on. They must operate with the folders in the child folder.
Thanks in advance!
I tried using
source("child_folder/script_n.R", chdir = T) 
but the error is
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : parent folder 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'child_folder/grand_child_folder/Data.dat': No such file or directory.


The script_n.R contains a code
    for (i in seq_len(rep)) {
      
      cat(i, "\r")
      
      # Simulate data
      dat <- simulateData(mod0, sample.nobs = nobs)
      
      write.table(dat, paste0("_Data_/Data_", i, ".dat"), col.names = FALSE, 
                  row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
      
    }

because the idea is to simulate data.
Each script_n.R sets their own working directory in the beginning using misty::setsource() so that all created files would be directed into right places. It seems that
source("child_folder/script_n.R", chdir = T) 
does not recognize the command misty::setsource() for setting the working directory. If I would change all the "_Data_/Data_" into form of "folder/_Data_/Data_", the source() would work. I really would like to avoid that because I would have hundreds of those commands to change.
I sent a question to the developer of misty to try solve this from that side, but meanwhile, is there any other option in other packages that could be used to write the run_all_scripts.R?
I also tried

## finds all .R and .r files within a folder and sources them
sourceFolder <- function(folder, recursive = FALSE, ...) 
{ 
  files <- list.files(folder, pattern = "[.][rR]$", 
                      full.names = TRUE, recursive = recursive)
  if (!length(files))
    stop(simpleError(sprintf('No R files in folder "%s"', folder)))
  src <- invisible(lapply(files, source, ...))
  message(sprintf('%s files sourced from folder "%s"', length(src), folder))
}

sourceFolder("child_folder", recursive = TRUE)

but it gives the same error.
I also tried
system("child_folder/script_n.R", intern = TRUE) 
but with no success.

What do you mean by “tabs”? In the context of R this isn’t a commonly understood term. Is it related to MplusAutomation?

Are you sure that tab_n.R doesn't contain code reading/loading the .dat file?

Thanks @KonradRudolph, I edited the text so that it would be more understandable.

OK, so the issue appears to be that your code tries to write a file to child folder/grand child folder/ and that directory doesn't exist. This doesn't have anything to do with "executing tabs" (I still have no idea what that is) but with ensuring directories exist (see help("dir.exists") and specifying a file path correctly (maybe study help("file.path") or possibly even help("normalizePath")). Also, you should avoid blank spaces in directory or file names.

@Roland “Also, you should avoid blank spaces in directory or file names” — No, that’s nonsense advice. Software that can’t deal with spaces in paths is defective. Don’t blame the user for wanting to do something that’s completely valid, sensible, and unproblematic unless you work with tools made by incompetent people.

Thanks, @Roland! I got a bit further, and again edited the text. I also changed all blank spaces (not that many) so that they are not causing the problem.
